# Using prediction from keras model as a layer inside another keras model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Suppose we have a model already trained for some task can we use that models prediction as a lambda layer inside another model? I am thinking something in the following format:

```
pretrained_model=get_Model()    #Loaded from a different file
pretrained_model.load_weights('pretrained_model_weights.h5')

base_model = VGG16(weights = 'imagenet',include_top=False,input_shape (240,320,3))

for layer in base_model.layers:
    layer.trainable = True

img_input=base_model.input
encoded=base_model.output

pretrained_model_output=Lambda(lambda x: pretrained_model.predict(img_input))

#Then run pretrained_model_output through an architecture that gives same output size as base_model.output and then 

concat = Concatenate([img_input,Output_Convolutions_pretrained_model_output],axis=-1)

#then feed this through another block in the model
```

Is something like this viable in Keras?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is much easier than you think, you just need to do:

```
pretrained_model_output= pretrained_model(img_input)
```

Comment: For that you need to set trainable to False (not to True)

Comment: I tried doing the same in my model, but I get the error `Inputs to eager execution function cannot be Keras symbolic tensors`
Any idea what this error wants to tell me?